# How can I scroll to last "article" of a form using a button?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a button that can automatically scroll when pressed to the last "post" / last article of a form. I've tried scrolling by percentage, but it doesn't work because not every post have the same height.
Now I understood that a better way to do this is by scrolling to the last article / last-child, but I don't know how to do this.

So, I got this button:

```
<button type='button' id='lastPost' class='ipsButton bigIcon_button' data-ipsTooltip title='Go to the last comment'><i class="fas fa-fast-forward"></i></button>
```

And I got a form like this:

```
<form action="https://lsgamerz.net/topic/7234-inside-project-lsgamerz-juliano-dillon-new-theme/?csrfKey=d74832284f92e0bdec551b0d50803919&amp;do=multimodComment" method="post" data-ipspageaction="" data-role="moderationTools"></form>
```

And there are more articles like this:

```
<article id="elComment_34910" class="cPost ipsBox ipsResponsive_pull  ipsComment  ipsComment_parent ipsClearfix ipsClear ipsColumns ipsColumns_noSpacing ipsColumns_collapsePhone    "></article>
```

So, as you can see, I have no class or id for the form and the article id is dynamically changing. I've never worked with Javascript before and I still regret that fact that I didn't learn it because now I'm stuck with this little things.

If you can help me making a code that when you press the button it scrolls down to the last article of the form leave a reply. I've searched all the internet, it just doesn't work for me, I've tried 20 different codes and still not scrolling where I want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, you could place an empty element around or above that last article with a constant, known ID and have your "button" be a link that simply href's to that other element. No JavaScript would be required.

```html
<!-- Give the below link button styling (make it look like a button -->
<a href="#lastarticle" class='ipsButton bigIcon_button'>Skip To Last Comment<i class="fas fa-fast-forward"></i></a> 
<!--
Your form, other articles, whatever is in between the button and the last article
...
...
-->
<div id="lastarticle"></div> <!-- Empty div that takes up no space, can also wrap the last article, if you'd like -->
<article id="elComment_34910" class="cPost ipsBox ipsResponsive_pull  ipsComment  ipsComment_parent ipsClearfix ipsClear ipsColumns ipsColumns_noSpacing ipsColumns_collapsePhone    "></article> <!-- the last article -->
```

If you want to use JavaScript to solve try getting all of the articles in your html document, selecting the last one, and then scroll to it. See below.

```js
function skipToLast(){
  // Get all elements with article tag
  var articles = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
  // Get the last article
  var lastArticle = articles[articles.length-1];
  // Scroll to that last article
  lastArticle.scrollIntoView();
}
```

```html
<!-- Add onclick="skipToLast()" to have the button call your JS function -->
<button onclick="skipToLast()" type='button' id='lastPost' class='ipsButton bigIcon_button' data-ipsTooltip title='Go to the last comment'><i class="fas fa-fast-forward"></i></button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @zahlawi! Your function work perfectly, also I've managed to make it scroll smoothso that's exactly what I was looking for! Also I found that it works even if there's only one article so that's pretty nice! God bless you.

Comment: Awesome Julian, glad I could help and God bless you as well!

Answer (score 1):

you can scroll to the last article of the form by this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#lastPost', function () {

  var form= document.getElementById("your_form_id");

  form.scrollTop = form.scrollHeight;

})
```

Comment: Thank you mate! I've used @zahlawi code and it works perfectly, but thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Made a function that uses the scrollIntoView() method.
The function grabs all of the articles, and then pick the last one and then uses the ScrollIntoView() method.

Hope this works for you!

```
//Button where you can place at the top of the page.
<input type="Button" onclick="lastArticle()" value="Press me for last article"/> 

//Code you put in a JS file och between script tags
const lastArticle = function () {
  const btn = document.querySelectorAll("article");
  const anchor = btn[btn.length - 1].scrollIntoView();
};
```

Here is a JSfiddle link for example.
https://jsfiddle.net/f8s3t67w/

Comment: Thank you mate! I've used @zahlawi code and it works perfectly, but thank you for your effort!

Comment: Happy to help :)